# Android SDK Samples Contain Many Errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sdk, sample

I've just recently installed the latest Android SDK (Android 4.1 API16) and the latest Eclipse (Juno Release).

When I open up the sample Android projects (via File > New > Project > Android > Android Sample Project) I get a bunch of errors in the code for many of the samples.

Most of them are "The method ****** must override a superclass method".

There are also a lot of "The constructor ****** is deprecated".

How can I get these errors to go away so that I can run the apps?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going through this path. Go through --> File --> New --> Other --> Android Sample Project --> Select Build target --> Select project and see if it works. At least it worked for me as after last step it showed Android projects listed in eclipse window itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check java compiler version. you can change this in project properties >> Java Compiler section. version should be 1.6 not 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your adt bundle and Window->AndroidSdkManager->Download all api level and try to do again.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install API's of the correct version.

Open the SDK manager and install the needed API versions which are missing.

Then clean the project and if needed rebuild.